# Due to a technical failure I was unable to rebook my flight

Tags: berlin, fare-basis

I have booked a flight with Sundair which is supposed to be tomorrow at 13:00 CEST. My booking allows me to rebook the flight up to 24 hours from the departure time. Due to personal reasons, I had to change the flight today morning (like 30 hours before departure). Unfortunately, the website showed me that all flights are sold out, even up to March 2023. After calling and sending several emails to the airline company, they confirmed to me that they are having a technical failure, and that the rebooking cannot be done. Unfortunately the 24 hours period has passed and I cannot rebook the ticket anymore.
Is there a way to claim my rights from the airline as they should take the responsibility for their website failure.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly ask. They may refund you or refuse. Unfortunately most airlines these days will drag their feet on refunds regardless if they are legally required to pay or not. It's just very hard to force them and they know it. They often try to makes this as tedious and complicated as possible, in the hopes that you will simply give up (which many people eventually do).

I would probably send a certified letter by mail stating that you were not able to exercise your rights to rebook due to a technical failure on their part. Add as much supporting documentation as you can. Ideally you would have transcripts of the phone calls and copies of the e-mail.

In parallel: give them a call. If you are lucky you may find a sympathetic agent. If they decline, ask for a supervisor. You can use some key terms like "Sunair has violated their own terms and conditions" , "Sunair prevented be from exercising my legal rights". This has no real legal relevance but its mumbo-jumbo to soften up the  agent  increase their risk-assessment of potential legal action.

Then follow up until you get your refund or you run out of energy. You could consider legal action but whether this makes sense depends on your local legal environment (and associated cost).